# CompletableFuture recoverWith equivalent? i.e. exceptionally but return CompletableFuture<U>

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I don't see an obvious way to handle an exception with an asynchronous result.

For example, if I want to retry an async operation, I would expect something like this:

```
CompletionStage<String> cf = askPong("cause error").handleAsync((x, t) -> {
    if (t != null) {
        return askPong("Ping");
    } else {
        return x;
    }
});
```

Where askPong asks an actor:

```
public CompletionStage<String> askPong(String message){
    Future sFuture = ask(actorRef, message, 1000);
    final CompletionStage<String> cs = toJava(sFuture);
    return cs;
}
```

However `handleAsync` doesn't do what you think it does - it runs the callbacks on another thread asynchronously. Returning a `CompletionStage` here is not correct.

Jeopardy question of the day: `thenApply` is to `thenCompose` as `exceptionally` is to what?

Comment: What does "is not correct" mean? What behavior are you looking for?

Comment: That won't compile. You can't return a CompletableFuture<U>  in <U>handleAsync - you have to return U. I'd like to be able to return a CompletableFuture<U> instead of a <U> in the exception case. I'm looking for the equivalent to scala or play promise recoverWith (which is like exceptionally but with an asynchronous result in the Function).

Comment: I tried to clarify a bit in the question itself. Maybe I'm not using handleAsync correctly but it doesn't mean "and return an async result".

Comment: exceptionally will be called on the thread that executed they async ask originally. So it should be already asynchronous to your main thread of execution. Do you need to resubmit to a task executor? Or is it possible to just make the call again on the same thread? I.e.  return askPong("Ping").join() is still asynchronous inside an exceptionally block.

Comment: I see your problem, you don't want to block the the thread that the error occured on while another askPong is executed on yet another thread. Unless you can specify the executor service used in askPong (you could then reuse the current thread - Executor exec = (Runnable r)  -> r.run()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of frustration in trying to figure out the proper way of doing Scala's recoverWith in Java 8, I ended up just writing my own. I still don't know if this is the best approach, but I created something like:

```
public RecoveryChainAsync<T> recoverWith(Function<Throwable,
                                         CompletableFuture<T>> fn);
```

With repeated calls to recoverWith, I queue up the functions inside the recovery chain and implement the recovery flow myself with "handle". RecoveryChainAsync.getCompletableFuture() then returns a representative CompletableFuture for the entire chain. Hope this helps.

Comment: Java8 lib is missing a bunch of stuff. I working on a library called better-java-monads - if you make a PR I can review your solution if you want. Might be a useful addition. I added a traverse for futures as well. https://github.com/jasongoodwin/better-java-monads

Comment: Hey thanks btw Jeff - yeah this is exactly the same thing I was running into I guess years ago lol

Answer (score 17):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
askPong("cause error")
        .handle( (pong, ex) -> ex == null 
                ? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(pong) 
                : askPong("Ping")
        ).thenCompose(x -> x);
```

Also, do not use the `...Async` methods unless you intend for the body of the supplied function to be executed asynchronously.  So when you do something like

```
.handleAsync((x, t) -> {
    if (t != null) {
        return askPong("Ping");
    } else {
        return x;
    })
```

You are asking for the `if-then-else` to be run in a separate thread.  Since `askPong` returns a `CompletableFuture`, there's probably no reason to run it asynchronously.

Comment: That's terrible. but it works. Thanks for the solution though! Didn't think of that. It is a hack though - there should be an exceptionallyCompose method in the API.

Comment: Kind of frustrating there isn't! I might end up using https://github.com/javaslang/javaslang which is a better Future interface

Answer (score 1):

> Jeopardy question of the day: `thenApply` is to `thenCompose` as `exceptionally` is to what?

I know this was initially [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), but, since [java-12](/questions/tagged/java-12), the answer would be `exceptionallyCompose`:

> [`exceptionallyCompose[Async](Function<Throwable,? extends CompletionStage<T>> fn [, Executor executor])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#exceptionallyCompose(java.util.function.Function))
>
> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes exceptionally, is composed using the results of the supplied function applied to this stage's exception.

As the JavaDoc indicates, the default implementation is:

```
return handle((r, ex) -> (ex == null)
              ? this
              : fn.apply(ex))
    .thenCompose(Function.identity());
```

That is, using `handle()` to call the fallback, and `thenCompose()` to unwrap the resulting nested `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<T>>` – i.e., what you would have done in previous versions of Java (like in [Misha’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28655228/525036)), except you would have to replace `this` with `completedFuture(r)`.