# Type mismatch when extending CompletableFuture

Tags: java, generics, completable-future

I am trying to extend `CompletableFuture` to do a `thenCompose` after `handle`, but I got a compiler error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from CompletableFuture(Object) to CompletableFuture(U)
```

This is my code:

```
public class MyCompletableFuture<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {

    public <U> CompletableFuture<U> handleAndCompose(BiFunction<? super T, Throwable, ? extends U> fn) {
        return super.handle(fn).thenCompose(x->x);
    }

}
```

For the record, I am trying to hide the `thenCompose` used on [this reponse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28655228/1369350) which is basically:

```
.handle((x, t) -> {
    if (t != null) {
        return askPong("Ping");
    } else {
        return x;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of your method is incorrect. It should be:

```
public <U> CompletableFuture<U> handleAndCompose(BiFunction<? super T, Throwable, ? extends CompletableFuture<U>> fn) {
    return super.handle(fn).thenCompose(x->x);
}
```

Note that the function given returns `? extends CompletableFuture<U>` instead of `? extends U`. You could also accept as argument a more general `CompletionStage` instead of a `CompletableFuture`.