# How to avoid invoking CompletableFuture.thenCompose(x -> x)?

Tags: java, completable-future

I get the feeling that I am misusing the [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#) API.

When invoking `CompletableFuture.exceptionally()` I routinely find myself needing to invoke another asynchronous process, which means that `exceptionally()` returns `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<T>>` instead of `CompletableFuture<T>`. I then cast the result back using `thenCompose(x -> x)`.

Here is a concrete example:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> listenersNotified = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
{
  int result = expensiveOperation();
  List<CompletionStage<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
  for (EventListener listener: listeners)
    listener.onSuccess(result);
  return futures;
}).thenCompose(futures -> CompletableFuture.allOf(futures)).
  exceptionally((exception) -> 
  {
    List<CompletionStage<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (EventListener listener: listeners)
      futures.add(listener.onError(result));
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);
  }).thenCompose(x -> x);
```

I understand that in the above example, one can `return futures` from inside `exceptionally()` and move `thenCompose()` after `exceptionally()` and this will work, but in real-life I don't always want to apply the same function to the result of `thenSupply()` as the result of `exceptionally()`. I want each section to take care of converting its own return type from a `CompletableFuture` to a synchronous value.

Is there a way to avoid falling into this pattern?

Comment: I don't think it is always possible to avoid it. `thenCompose()` is the _compose_  equivalent of `thenApply()`. To be able to avoid it in all cases, we would need _compose_ equivalents for all other methods taking a `Function` or `BiFunction` argument, i.e. `applyToEither()`, `exceptionnally()`, `handle()`, `thenCombine()` with all their `*Async()` overloads. That would mean at least 12 new methods, and I think they didn't want to bloat the API when you can simply use one of those followed by `thenCompose(x - x)`. I agree it would be convenient though, especially for exception handling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java8 CompletableFuture recoverWith equivalent? eg exceptionally but return CompletableFuture<U>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652291/java8-completablefuture-recoverwith-equivalent-eg-exceptionally-but-return-comp)