# CompletableFuture compose for exceptions

Tags: java, completable-future

The `CompletableFuture` API allows us to use `thenCompose` to chain another future:

```java
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = submit("foo");
CompletableFuture<String> future2 = future.thenCompose((result) -> submit(result));
```

This only works for successful responses though. Is there a way to do the same but also including exception handling?

For example:

```java
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = submit("foo");
CompletableFuture<String> future2 = future.handleCompose((result, error) -> {
  if (error != null)
    return submit("failure"); // Handle error by doing a different action with the same result (like a fallback)
  else
    return submit(result);
});
```

I know you can do something like `whenComplete`:

```java
CompletableFuture<String> future2 = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = submit("foo");
future.whenComplete((result, error) -> {
  CompletableFuture<String> tmp;
  if (error != null)
    tmp = submit("failure");
  else
    tmp = submit(result);
  tmp.whenComplete((result2, error2) -> {
    if (error2 != null) future2.completeExceptionally(error2);
    else future2.complete(result2);
  });
});
```

This however loses the ability to cancel properly and seems like a very "hacky" solution compared to the success composition handling. Is there a good way that does not require making my own extension of the CompletableFuture class?

The problem is that I need to return a single future from my method and it should be capable to cancel the entire process at any point in time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine an [`handle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) returning a `CompletableFuture` with a `thenCompose(x -> x)`:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future2 = future.handle((result, error) -> {
  if (error != null)
    return submit("failure"); // Handle error by doing a different action with the same result (like a fallback)
  else
    return submit(result);
})
.thenCompose(x -> x);
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid that last `thenCompose()`. See also [How to avoid invoking `CompletableFuture.thenCompose(x -> x)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51217350/525036) and my comment on it.

Edit: for Java 12+ there is now `exceptionallyCompose()`, which I described as [an answer on this question’s duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70746175/525036).

Comment: Are you sure this works? From what I can tell `exceptionally` expects a `Function<Throwable, ? extends T>` so it has to return `String`

Comment: Sorry, it is `handle()`, not `exceptionally()` – I copied it a bit too fast from the other question.

Comment: I’d simplify the syntax: `future2 = future.handle((result, error) -> error != null? submit("failure"): submit(result)) .thenCompose(x -> x);` Or even `future2 = future.handle((result, error) -> submit(error != null? "failure": result)) .thenCompose(x -> x);` But note that this does not fulfill the “it should be capable to cancel the entire process at any point in time” requirement. Calling cancel on the resulting future will only cancel the `.thenCompose(x -> x)` step. That’s a general problem of `CompletableFuture`’s fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of CompletableFuture.allOf(..), This is not the only solution but it is better.

```
public CompletableFuture<String> getSomeDataFromExternalIfPossible() {
    var input = "SomeKey";
    CompletableFuture<String> externalDataFetchCFuture = getDataFromExternal(input);
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(externalDataFetchCFuture)
        .exceptionally(
            ex -> {
              // This exceptionally(...) is required as allOf(...) propagates exception thrown by any of the supplied futures
              // Log if you are interested in failed case of externalDataFetchCFuture
              return null;
            })
        .thenCompose(
            unused -> {
              // Check if externalDataFetchCFuture completed successfully and invoke other Async method if not
              if (!externalDataFetchCFuture.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
                // On externalDataFetchCFuture successful execution
                return externalDataFetchCFuture;
              } else {
                // On externalDataFetchCFuture failed execution
                // Fetching data from DB or from any other integration
                return getDataFromExternal2(input);
              }
            });
}

private CompletableFuture<String> getDataFromExternal(String input) {
  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("abc");
}

private CompletableFuture<String> getDataFromExternal2(String input) {
  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("xyz");
}
```